# PHP will not create mysql table, but can be entered manually.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table for an item's bid history upon the items insertion to the items table.

I am getting this error:

> > Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''19' ( user_pk INT(20)unsigned, maxbid DECIMAL(16,8)un' at line
>   1
>
> create table item'19' ( user_pk INT(20)unsigned, maxbid
>   DECIMAL(16,8)unsigned, bid DECIMAL(16,8)unsigned, ip VARCHAR(80),
>   winning BOOLEAN NULL )
>
> Filename:
>   /home/content/61/11420661/html/btcbidder.com/controllers/user.php
>
> Line Number: 253

The code for that line is:

```
                        $this->db->query("CREATE TABLE item'$currentId' (
                                            user_pk INT(20)unsigned,
                                            maxbid DECIMAL(16,8)unsigned,
                                            bid DECIMAL(16,8)unsigned,
                                            ip VARCHAR(80),
                                            winning BOOLEAN NULL
                                            )");
```

If I create the table manually by entering something like item23 for the table name into SQL query browser, the table is created successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also - are you sure you need a new table for this? You could have a single `item` table, with an `itemID` as one column.

Comment: @andrewsi, I have a separate table which holds all the items, thier item photo path, title, description, and the sellers minumum price. This table would record all the bids for that item, and the table would be dropped when the item is removed by the user, or staff, or 30 days past item expiration.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, using . to concatenate query string and variable.

```
$this->db->query("CREATE TABLE item". $currentId ." (
                                        user_pk INT(20)unsigned,
                                        maxbid DECIMAL(16,8)unsigned,
                                        bid DECIMAL(16,8)unsigned,
                                        ip VARCHAR(80),
                                        winning BOOLEAN NULL
                                        )");
```